# iPhone/xCode - EXC_BAD_ACCESS on 4th run of Animation Code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode, animation

This code works for the first 3 times, and every time without fail, it crashes on the 4th run, with a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4)`. I have researched all afternoon, but have come up with nothing, is it that I am not releasing something?

```
- (void)animateImageView:(UIImageView *)imageViewForAnimation
{
        imageViewForAnimation.alpha = 1.0f;
        CGRect imageFrame = imageViewForAnimation.frame;
        //Your image frame.origin from where the animation need to get start
        CGPoint viewOrigin = imageViewForAnimation.frame.origin;
        viewOrigin.y = viewOrigin.y + imageFrame.size.height / 2.0f;
        viewOrigin.x = viewOrigin.x + imageFrame.size.width / 2.0f;

        imageViewForAnimation.frame = imageFrame;
        imageViewForAnimation.layer.position = viewOrigin;
        [self.view addSubview:imageViewForAnimation];

        // Set up fade out effect
        CABasicAnimation *fadeOutAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        [fadeOutAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3]];
        fadeOutAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        fadeOutAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

        // Set up scaling
        CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
        [resizeAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(40.0f, imageFrame.size.height * (40.0f / imageFrame.size.width))]];
        resizeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        resizeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

        // Set up path movement
        CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
        pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        //Setting Endpoint of the animation
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(250.0f, 10.0f);
        //to end animation in last tab use
        //CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake( 320-40.0f, 480.0f);
        CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, viewOrigin.x, viewOrigin.y);
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, endPoint.x, viewOrigin.y, endPoint.x, viewOrigin.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
        pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
        CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

        CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
        group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fadeOutAnimation, pathAnimation, resizeAnimation, nil]];
        group.duration = 0.7f;
        group.delegate = self;
        //[group setValue:@"groupAnimation" forKey:@"animationName"];
        [group setValue:imageViewForAnimation forKey:@"imageViewBeingAnimated"];

        [imageViewForAnimation.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"savingAnimation"];


        [imageViewForAnimation release];

}
```

Comment: Remove the release. Even better, use ARC

Comment: Thank you so much, I just wasted 4 hours on that one line. I am interested, why does the release do that. And how would I implement ARC

Comment: ARC you just go to the menu bar in Xcode, Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC... then follow along carefully. It will remove retains and releases from Obj-C stuff.

Comment: My advice works because the object imageViewForAnimation was a parameter of your method and nothing in your method is adding a retain to the object. So it makes sense that the imageViewForAnimation object's retain count was being decremented unnecessarily. Only release when you have retained. Keep those in the same scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the release. 
My advice works because the object imageViewForAnimation was a parameter of your method and nothing in your method is adding a retain to the object. So it makes sense that the imageViewForAnimation object's retain count was being decremented unnecessarily. Only release when you have retained. Keep those in the same scope.

Even better, use ARC 
ARC you just go to the menu bar in Xcode, Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC... then follow along carefully. It will remove retains and releases from Obj-C stuff.